# HTTP/REST API wrappers of COM/IDL interfaces?

Tags: rest, http, com, idl

I'm working on a project where we're maintaining object-oriented [COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal) interfaces defined in [Interface Definition Language (IDL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/anatomy-of-an-idl-file) files. This allows for simple & efficient consumption from C++, C# and Python (using `comtypes`) when running on the same Windows computer as the service provider. However, communication is currently bound to a single computer.

My organization is currently encountering use-cases where it would be useful to be able to call the same interfaces remotely from a different computer. I understand that HTTP/REST is currently the "standard" way of exposing remote APIs over a network. I'm therefore interested in any SW that could streamline the process of generating a HTTP/REST (or similar) wrapper server of existing COM/IDL interfaces. I'm fully aware that the generated interfaces will probably not adhere to REST "best practice" guidelines. Just want a auto-generated solution to avoid having to manually maintain a wrapper APIs myself.

Comment: The usual way of accessing COM components remotely is via DCOM. If the remote system understands COM it might be worth using DCOM for remote access

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I fear DCOM could restrict compatibility for non-Windows clients compared to HTTP/REST. Also, firewalls could cause problems if the DCOM port is not opened. I would therefore prefer a portable API technology if possible.

Comment: COM/DCOM uses RPC as a transport mechanism. There was once (~20 years ago) a way to expose DCOM over HTTP using "RPC over HTTP Proxy Support" that's in Windows. I'm not even sure it can still be enabled/used since I can only find the doc to *remove* this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/825819/how-to-remove-com-internet-services-cis-and-rpc-over-http-proxy-suppor . Said differently, there's nothing modern built in Windows for you in that area, AFAIK.